Make4ht fatal error on otherwise compiling document
I am trying to turn the project https://github.com/susanszkyp/IntroToLogicTextbook into something that could then be hacked into an ebook platform built on Wordpress. I tried a few solutions for converting LaTeX to HTML but so far, nothing worked very well (or at all).
The most recent attempt has been with Make4ht. Strangely, when I call it on the main document textbook_main.tex, it puts up a bunch of error messages like LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document} (clearly there), Undefined control sequence and Missing \endcsname inserted, then exits with a fatal error (exit code 1). But I don't really know what to look for since the project otherwise compiles into a PDF without problem. What could be the clash here?
In general, I would be happy with a minimal solution where macros and minimal formatting (italics, enumerate, tables, amsthm etc.) would be turned into HTML, and all math environments and figures (esp. tikz, forest, and prooftrees) would be turned into  SVG - without me doing it all by hand.

"LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document} (clearly there)," the error means that there is something before the begin document that should not be, not that there is no \begin{document}  eg \documentclass{article} oops \begin{document}\end{document} will give that error. The full error from the log will give  the context but you have shown neither the input nor full error message.

The fatal error seems to be caused by using \RequirePackage[table]{xcolor} together with TikZ. If you use \RequirePackage{xcolor}\RequirePackage{colortbl}, this error goes away. Then there is a lot of errors caused by using of \mathbb as an argument of superscripts or subscripts without proper grouping. Always use ${x}^{\mathbb{x}}$ to prevent such errors.

The fatal error seems to be caused by a clash between TeX4ht, TikZ and Xcolor packages. I cannot find a solution at TeX4ht side, but workaround is easy. In logictextbook.sty, replace \RequirePackage[table]{xcolor} with:
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{colortbl}

This should fix the fatal error at \begin{document}.
There is also other issue. You use lot of superscripts and subscripts with inproper grouping:
$\mathcal{L}_\mathbb{N}$

The correct form is this:
 ${\mathcal{L}}_{\mathbb{N}}$

So to get the correct form, you would need to edit your sources and change all of these. Other possibility is to use picture math even for inline math. In this case, TeX4ht handling of sub- and superscripts is turned off. The downside is that this produces a huge number of SVG files. 4384 to be exact. To get that compile your file using:
$ make4ht -f html5+dvisvgm_hashes -m draft -a debug textbook_main.tex "svg,pic-m,pic-align"

